# matplotlib: multiple plots on one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def print_fractures(fractures):
    xpairs = []
    ypairs = []
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(212)
    for i in range(len(fractures)):
        xends = [fractures[i][1][0], fractures[i][2][0]]
        yends = [fractures[i][1][1], fractures[i][2][1]]
        xpairs.append(xends)
        ypairs.append(yends)
    for xends,yends in zip(xpairs,ypairs):
        plt.plot(xends, yends, 'b-', alpha=0.4)
    plt.show()


def histogram(spacings):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.hist(spacings, 100)
    plt.xlabel('Spacing (m)', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency (count)', fontsize=15)
    plt.show()

histogram(spacings)    
print_fractures(fractures)
```

This code will produce the following output:
[image: Fig1]

My questions are:

1) Why are two separate figures being created? I thought the subplot command would combine them into one figure. I thought it might be the multiple plt.show() commands, but I tried commenting those out and only calling it once from outside my functions and I still got 2 windows.

2) How can I combine them into 1 figure properly? Also, I would want figure 2 axes to have the same scale (i.e. so 400 m on the x axis is the same length as 400 m on the y-axis). Similarly, I'd like to stretch the histogram vertically as well - how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you observed already, you cannot call `figure()` inside each function if you intend to use only one figure (one Window). Instead, just call `subplot()` without calling `show()` inside the function. The `show()` will force `pyplot` to create a second figure IF you are in `plt.ioff()` mode. In `plt.ion()` mode you can keep the `plt.show()` calls inside the local context (inside the function).

To achieve the same scale for the x and y axes, use `plt.axis('equal')`. Below you can see an illustration of this prototype:

```
from numpy.random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def print_fractures():
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

def histogram():
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.hist(random(1000), 100)
    plt.xlabel('Spacing (m)', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency (count)', fontsize=15)

histogram()
print_fractures()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```