# multiple graph (not subplot) using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I would like to plot two or more graphs at once using `python` and `matplotlib`.  I do not want to use subplot since it is actually two or more plots on the same drawing paper.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` will open a new figure window for you, if that's what you mean.

Comment: you can always do your figure bigger by using `figsize=(width,height)` specifying width and height in inches inside `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` and then use subplots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: multiple plots on one figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321764/matplotlib-multiple-plots-on-one-figure)

Comment: @WKK I don't think it's clear what you mean by "two or more plots on the same drawing paper". Can you edit the question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple figures and plot some data in each of them. The easiest way of doing so is to call `plt.figure()` and use the pyplot statemachine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure() # creates a figure
plt.plot([1,2,3])

plt.figure() # creates a new figure
plt.plot([3,2,1])

plt.show() # opens a window for each of the figures
```

If for whatever reason after creating a second figure you want to plot to the first one, you need to 'activate' it via

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([2,3,1]) # this is plotted to the first figure.
```

(Figure numbers start at 1)